# I am getting a syntax error when creating a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I try to create a trigger but I get this error after executing the SQL:

> # 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE temp INT' at line 4

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hesap 

AFTER INSERT ON uber  

 DECLARE temp INT;

 BEGIN    IF uber.il='ANKARA' THEN 
  temp=5+(uber.mesafe*0.5);  

 ELSEIF uber.il='ISTANBUL' THEN  
 temp=10+(uber.mesafe*0.5);   

ELSEIF uber.il='IZMIR' THEN  
 temp=3+(uber.mesafe*0.5);  

 END IF; 
     
INSERT INTO fatura VALUES(uber.uid,temp)

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax error as I identified check out the below code:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER hesap 
AFTER INSERT ON uber FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

DECLARE temp integer;

    IF new.il = 'ANKARA' THEN
        temp= 5+(uber.mesafe*0.5);
    ELSEIF new.il='ISTANBUL' THEN  
        temp=10+(uber.mesafe*0.5);   
    ELSEIF new.il='IZMIR' THEN  
        temp=3+(uber.mesafe*0.5);
    END IF;
INSERT INTO fatura VALUES(new.uid,temp);

END
delimiter ;
```